# Acrobat Reader DC Comment Frame Disabling

Tags: adobe-reader

Is there any other way to disable comment frame that's on the right section? Whenever I open a PDF file to read, it is being opened comment sidebar. I couldn't find the solution in the preferences.

[image: http://zinzinzibidi.com/img/adobe-reader-sidebar.png]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to embed the picture from the link into the question - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You may create DWORD named `bExpandRHPInViewer` with value `0` at `[HKCU\Software\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\DC\AVGeneral]`. And DWORD `bRHPSticky` with value `1` hides tools pane, which is also annoying. Code for `*.reg` file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\DC\AVGeneral]
"bExpandRHPInViewer"=dword:00000000
"bRHPSticky"=dword:00000001
```